# Is there any way to check parameter exist in Laravel previous URL

Tags: php, laravel

Want to check the previous URL contains the parameter and want to get the value of the particular paramter from the previous URL like from the current URL we can check.

```
 if(request()->has('status')){
    //current url 
    }

 example.com/leads/personal?status=custom&userid=512
```

Comment: How did you come from previous url, from your blade obviously, post that blade code

Comment: @sta what for? It doesn't matter.

Comment: Your current url hold the param `status=custom&userid=512`?

Comment: previous URL in the middleware by using  url()->previous()

Comment: my previous URL contains the parameter and i want to add with current URL that is my task

Comment: Yes, that's why I told you to post the blade code, how you reach the current url. So you can add the param there

Comment: Can't you just keep user's last parameter in user's session?

Comment: I can add with the in blade code with route function, I looking for a solution if I can add in middleware.like route('xyz',['status'=>'custom', 'userid' =>'512'])

Comment: Using laravel for android webview pages, session does not work their @amin

Comment: Catct the url parameter from blade as `{{ Request::get('status') }}` so in your previous url method would be, `<a href="/leads/personal?status={{Request::get('status')}}&userid={{Request::get('userid')}}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's easy out of the box. I would suggest installing the [spatie/url](https://github.com/spatie/url) package and then:

```php
use Spatie\Url\Url;

$previousUrl = Url::fromString(url()->previous());

if ($previousUrl->hasQueryParameter('status')) {
    // ...
}
```